# Draw fractal Fit inside panel using Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

i am trying to build a windows application in .net which draw fractal image inside the panel.It take end points of line as starting point of next line.But problem is, diagram is going outside of the panel.How do i fix drawing inside the panel

```
        static int start_x, start_Y;
        static int end_x, end_Y;
        static int my_angle = 0;
        static int my_length = 0;

    private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        start_x = Canvas.Width / 2;
        start_Y = Canvas.Height / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
        {
            draw_T();
        }
    }

    public void draw_T()
    {
       Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2F);
        my_angle = my_angle + (45);
        my_length = 100 + (1);

        end_x = (int)(start_x + Math.Cos(my_angle * .0174539676) * my_length);

        end_Y = (int)(start_Y + Math.Sin(my_angle * .0174539676) * my_length);

        Point[] points =
        {
            new Point (start_x,start_Y),
            new Point (end_x,end_Y)
        };
        Point[] points1 =
        {
            new Point ((end_x+start_x)/2,(end_Y+start_Y)/2),
            new Point (end_x+50,end_Y-100)
        };
        start_x = end_x;
        start_Y = end_Y;
        Graphics g = Canvas.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawLines(mypen, points);
        g.DrawLines(mypen, points1);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably scale the the drawing to the size of the canvas. Adjust either the algorithm or scale the image.

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you graphic is supposed to look but I can give you a couple of hints.

At general one first: Do make use of `e.Graphics` parameter! Change

```
public void draw_T()
```

To

```
public void draw_T(Graphics g)
```

and delete the line.

```
Graphics g = Canvas.CreateGraphics();
```

Change the call to

```
draw_T(e.Graphics);
```

You are leaking GDI resource by creating all those Graphcs with disposing of them and and lose time by creating them when you already have the one from the Paint event.

Next you should add a `NumericUpDown` for testing your algorithm and script it like this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.Invalidate();
}
```

To work you now change the loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
```

And watch your graphics develop.

Another test could be to introduce a second pen color for the second series of point.
To play around further you could add another `NumericUpDown` and tie `my_length`to it..

In the end you'll see that length needs to be smaller than 101 or the Canvas needs to be as large as 700 pixels.

BTW: Neither `my_angle` nor  `my_length` need to be declared at class level since they are always set in the method and used nowhere else and no other variable needs to `static` either, at least from what you show us..